# Recurring errors in Loop ( SSIS )

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package where I am processing some files in a `ForEach` loop. 
In the loop I have a data flow task which does the processing. I have made sure that the loop doesn't stop even if there is bad file by setting the `maxerror count` of the loop to `0`. I tried to catch the error in a message box using the script task on `ON ERROR` Event handler of the loop container. Instead of getting one error , I get three.
`Popagate` is set to `false` on the data flow’s `OnPostExecute` event. 
Please help.

Main package - Loop Task - Data Flow Task 
[image]

Comment: Can you show the design of your package ?

Comment: Praveen. Please check the screenshot. Doesn't appear proper in my browser though. Control flow , data flow & the event handler for the loop. Just a script task to tell the error. The derived column, if encouters an error , populates the error 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting 1 or more errors in the `script task` for `on Error` event handler is because in case of any error  inside the child controls for the container , the event is raised from the `Data Flow task` to the `ForEach` which is furthr carried upto the `package level`.More over setting `propogate` variable to `false` won't work in this case because `MaximumErrorCount` which you set to `0 overrides` any `propogate` settings in its child components.

Generally i try to create one `ErrorCount` variable of `type int` and in the script task for the event handler of the DFT i check the count

```
if (int.Parse(Dts.Variables["User::ErrorCount"].Value.ToString ()) == 0)
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::ErrorCnt"].Value = 1;
            //Do your logging operation or any operation
        }
```

So in this way the first time event handler is fired ,it sets the variable `ErrorCount` to 1 so  subsequent errors in DFT will fail the IF condition inside script task.

If you just have one component inside the ForEach loop ,i suggest you to use either of the below method

1. `MaxErrorCount` property for the ForEach Loop
2. Create a `event handler` for the `DFT` .Set the `propogate` variable to `False` and write the above code to check for number of errors.

I generally tend to use the 2nd method instead of Setting `MaxErrorCount`because that give me more flexibility to handle individual component level errors

For more details check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140223.aspx) MSDN link which explains how event handlers in SSIS works

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The second method worked as expected.